# comprehensive dict with multiple or repeated values in python3

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, functional-programming, list-comprehension

I have an extensive list with tuples of pairs. It goes like this:

```
travels =[(passenger_1, destination_1), (passenger_2, destination_2),(passenger_1, destination_2)...]
```

And so on. Passengers and destinations may repeat and even the same passenger-destination tuple may repeat.
I want to make a comprehensive dict thay have as key each passenger and as value its most recurrent destination.

My first try was this:

```
dictionary = {k:v for k,v in travels}
```

but each key overwrites the last. I was hoping to get multiple values for each key so then i could count for each key. Then I tried like this:

```
dictionary = {k:v for k,v in travels if k not in dictionary else dictionary[k].append(v)}
```

but i can't call dictionary inside its own definition. Any ideas on how can i get it done? It's important that it's done comprehensively and not by loops.

Answer (score 1):

That is how it can be done with for loop:

```
result = dict()
for passenger, destination in travels:
    result.setdefault(passenger, list()).append(destination)
```

`result` is a single dictionary where keys are passengers, values are lists with destinations.

I doubt you can do the same with a single dictionary comprehesion expression since inside comprehension you can just generate elements but can not freely modify them.

EDIT.

If you want to (or have to) use comprehension expression no matter what then you can do it like this (2 comprehensions and no explicit loops):

```
result = {
    passenger: [destination_
                for passenger_, destination_
                in travels
                if passenger_ == passenger]
    for passenger, dummy_destination
    in travels}
```

This is a poor algorithm to get what you want. Its efficiency is O(n^2) while efficiency of the first method is O(n).

Comment: Thats my issue. It doesn't need to be just one expression, I could have other steps but I can't use a for like the one you showed. I tried like this: dict1 = {k: list().append(v) for k, v in travels} but every value gets setted to none, as i need some value to be there first in order to append

Comment: @DanBerezin I edited my answer and added another solution to your problem (highly ineffective one).

Comment: It is very slow but it worked and it is sort of what i was looking for. Thanks.